# CSS percentage behavior

Tags: html, css, liquid

I'm having some strange behavior of the percentages.
I have layout which is 1366 pixels wide and I have one div which should be fluid.
Its 200px wide, which means it should be 14.64% wide.
When the layout is tested in 1366 pixels the div looks fine and there are no problems, but when I expand to 1920 the div is not wide enough.
Here is some samples of the code:
HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="top-bar">
        <div class="fill"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-bar">
    </div>
</header>
```

And CSS

```
.container{
    width: 1004px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 95px;
}

header div.top-bar{
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

header div.fill{
    background: #000000;
    width: 14.64%;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

nav{
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

header.main div.bottom-bar{
    background: url("header-bottom.png") repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
}
```

I've coded liquid designs before, but never had problem like this, maybe my math is wrong or the problem is that everything else is hardcoded in pixels and this is liquid?

Comment: correct me if i am wrong are you using fill to set container then add 
header div.fill{
    background: #000000;
     min-width:14.64%;
    width: 14.64%;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

Comment: Container has margin: 0px auto; and it aligns in the middle of the page. The idea of the fill div is to fill the left part before the container - from the left page border to the container(nav).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0ow7hm9w/ see here on changing screen size fill size also changing

Comment: you were saying you want something to be `1366px` wide... i don't see the `1366` anywhere in your css. and do you expect `14.64%` of 1366 and 1920 to be the same? if something needs to be `200px` wide, why can't you specify `200px` instead of `14.64%`? for me, your question is totally unclear.

Comment: I suggest you to use percentage values for all the elements instead of using pixels.For the container class also.

Comment: TJ, for me you are reading between the lines or you have never done some job like this before. Before the "writing code" starts you get someone who is called "designer" he makes the design for you in mostly cases you get it in Photoshop Design file (PSD) WHICH have some WIDTH and HEIGHT. In my case the width of the document side to side is 1366, so probably I should calculate the width of fluid element according to this width, shouldnt I?

Buddhi, Its not an option in my case, case the rest of the layout is fixed, only this element has liquid size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess the problem is because container has a pixel size while fill is in percentage. If all you want to achieve with the fill is to put a background color around container, you can do something like this (and remove the fill class css)

```
.container{
    width: 1004px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    background: #ffffff;
}

header div.top-bar{

    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000000;
}
```

Now if you want to color only left side, and want to fit your 'fill' div nicely, then both container and fill have be either in percentage or in pixels (won't work properly in different screen sizes). There are different workarounds to make your fill work e.g. the following

```
header div.fill {
background: #000000;
width: 50%; /*make it wide enough*/
height: 50px;
float: left;
z-index: -1; /*put it behind container*/
position: relative;
}

header div.top-bar{
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: -2; /*put it behind all*/
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I thought about this in the first, but its really an option, because the idea is to have the black color (#000000) only on the left of the container, on the right side it should be the background color.

Comment: I completed it with background-gradient which has 50% black and the other 50% is white so no problems, but I don't think that this is the right way, there must be other solution.

Comment: Have edited answer with one possible (not the best) workaround. But, pixels and percentage does never play nicely together. If it's not a very small project, I'd highly recommend having a look at Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Thank you! :) I heard a lot for bootstrap, but never got the balls for giving him a chance. I'm afraid that it has a lot of features(buttons, dropdowns and etc) that I will never use. :/

Comment: It has a lot of features, and you might not need all of them. But, if your projects grows considerably, you'll end up using most of them. And once you are used to it, you'll not want to come back to writing your css from scratch. It's lot of work, and maintaining over long time (and for different screens) is a nightmare in itself!

Answer (score 0):

for managment layout use grid system css famework for example

Bootstrap

http://getbootstrap.com/

or

960 grid system

http://960.gs/